# Is there a multi-directory DirectoryCatalog available in MEF or open source?

Tags: .net, mef

I'd like to separate extensions into their own subdirectory of some *Extensions* directory. I can specify multiple `DirectoryCatalog` of course and put them into an `AggregateCatalog`. But I have to go scan that directory and create those. Not a big deal, but is there something like `MultiDirectoryCatalog` out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope the best you will be able to do is an AggregateCatalog with a multiple DirectoryCatalogs. At least with what ships in the .NET Framework itself.